# Sort array by different values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

First of all, I looked much at already existing questions but can’t figure out anyone, which describes my problem.

I have the following array structure:

```
Array(
    0 => Array(
        [customerID] => 3
        [forename] => 
        [name] => 
        [company] => Third company
    )

    1 => Array(
        [customerID] => 2
        [forename] => Jane
        [name] => Smith
        [company] => 
    )

    2 => Array(
        [customerID] => 1
        [forename] => John
        [name] => Smith
        [company] => Best Company
    )
)
```

In general I want to print the forename and (last) name inside a HTML select field. It works fine for the last two array keys but not for the first one, because it has no forename or (last) name. It is no problem to print the company name instead but the problem is the order.

I select the array from the database with `ORDER BY forename ASC` and thus the array with no forename and (last) name everytime is the first value. 
In this case I want the order to be Array(1), Array(2), Array(0) so that the alphabetical order is still present (Jane, John, Third company) but I can’t figure out how to achieve this type of sorting in order to respect the forename key as well as the company key and sort them in a combination.

If the company name would be `Beta` Array(0) should stay at the first place, if the company name would be `Jesse James Ltd.` it should be ordered between the two other arrays.

Any advice would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sort the rows according to columns and in case the column value is empty, it'll be shown at the end of the result.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY IF(foreName = '', 1, 0), foreName;
```

**Edit**

Okay, from what I understand, this should work. Feel free to tell me if this is not what you desire.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY CONCAT(foreName, company);
```

The idea is basically joining the two columns and sorting according to it.

Comment: My question seems to be a little unclear. The order should be an alphabetical order. If the company name would be `Beta` it should stay the first item.

Comment: So basically, you want to order rows by foreName and if foreName is empty then company column should be used, is that correct @KittMedia?

Comment: Yes, but it should respect the other rows, which already were sorted by `forename` as well. So the values should be sorted by the value in `forename` and if empty the row should be sorted by the value of `company`.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Sorting in ascending order by `forename` field but placing records with empty values to the end of rowset:

```
SELECT customerID, forename, name, company
FROM table 
ORDER BY IF (`forename` <> '', 0, 1) ASC
```

Comment: My question seems to be a little unclear. The order should be an alphabetical order. If the company name would be `Beta` it should stay the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use (if) conditions to check for blank values and skip it?

Comment: I don’t want to skip them and place them at the end; I want to sort them in an alphabetical order by using `forename` and `company` as reference.

Comment: "So the values should be sorted by the value in forename and if empty the row should be sorted by the value of company" 
If this is what you want then i think it would be a quite hard using SQL. . Okay will i be correct to say that you basically want result in a for where all the value for "company" if it is blank, should be placed at the bottom of the array?